# Stress test angularJS application (Jmeter)

Tags: angularjs, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, stress-testing

I have Jmeter and webdriver plugin (chrome, firefox, phantomJS, ...)

1. The problem is when I launch the scenario with multi threads all headless (Chrome, PhantomJS) open the first thread and log into but all other threads don't log in, the reason we are already connected on the application (the aim have several users same time on the application), I don't know how to isolate session like firefox (the problem with firefox is not headless and only version 45 works)
2. I try to test recording controller via proxy and test recording in workbench but when i try to relaunch test the request don't go well (asynchrone) there is an explication tells "use transaction controller" then well but how ? i don't want to go on blazemater website i want to make it work locally anyone could make it work ? nobody stress test angularJS application ?

I prefer the 2nd solution call the browser via jmeter and test ajax via the http request but i don't know how it works

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many users do you need:

1. You can parameterize your test so different JMeter Threads (virtual users) would use different credentials to log into the application from different browsers via i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG). All browsers which are kicked off by the WebDriver Sampler should be isolated from each other and given you use different credentials you should be good to go. But it will only play for **several** users, as per [WebDriver Sampler 10 Minute Guide](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/#10-Minute-Guide)

   > However, for the Web Driver use case, the reader should be **prudent in the number of threads** they will create as each thread will have a single browser instance associated with it. **Each browser consumes a significant amount of resources**, and a limit should be placed on how many browsers the reader should create.
2. If you go the [HTTP Requests](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) way the easiest option to mimic AJAX calls would be putting them under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) so your test would look like:

   - Transaction Controller

     - Main Request
     - Parallel Controller

       - AJAX request 1
       - AJAX request 2
       - etc.

Comment: there is not parallel controller in jmeter 3.3 and what is the main request ? because i use recording controller to record specifiq scenario, indeed i have all request to play but in parallel... thanks

Comment: i add bzm Parallel controller, then i record a scenario, but when i move all cases under parallel tests and run it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, i make a simple configuration and it works, my angularJS application is embedded in a war but i don't know if it is doing a difference the structure is like this:

- Plan

  - Thread Group

    - HTTP Cookie Manager
    - HTTP Header Manager
    - HTTP request Defaults
    - Recording Controller

I recorded the scenario and simply play it (i assume that the login is in the right order) it is html pages i don't see the JS because the application is in application server